# Using Savon and nokogiri to make a Soap Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, nokogiri, savon

A sample request that I am trying to make looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <listRequest i:type="b:NpsListRequest" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.List" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.List.Strategies">
        <a:id>1</a:id>         
      </listRequest>
    </GetList>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I can replicate that exactly, using Nokogiri, like so:

```
    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml['s'].Envelope('xmlns:s' => "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/") {
        xml['s'].Body {
          xml.GetList('xmlns' => "http://tempuri.org/") {
            xml.listRequest('i:type' => "b:NpsListRequest", 'xmlns:a' => "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.List", 'xmlns:i' => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", 'xmlns:b' => "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.List.Strategies") {
              xml['a'].id(1)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    end

    builder.to_xml
```

Then, I build my soap_client using Savon:

```
def soap_client
      soap_client = Savon.client(
        wsdl: "http://1.1.1.1/Api.svc?wsdl", #PLE
        headers: {"Authorization" =>  "Basic"},
        basic_auth: ['user', 'password'],
        env_namespace: :soapenv,
        namespace_identifier: :ser,
        ssl_verify_mode: :none,
        log: true,
        :pretty_print_xml => true
    )
  end
```

Now, I need to make a `:get_list` call that looks like the above sample request.

`soap_client.operations` returns this:

`[:get_list]` So I know I'm authenticated and the client is working correctly.

I can't figure out how to actually make the `:get_list` call.

I would like something simple where I don't even have to use `Nokogiri` to build my own xml, like this:

`soap_client.call :get_list, message: {id => 1}`

But that doesn't seem to be a feasible solution. Any thoughts on how I can pass the XML I'm building using Nokogiri through to the `:get_list` call for my `soap_client`? I am open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: `soap_client.call :get_list, xml: builder.to_xml` This is what I ended up doing to pass the xml in, but I ended up finding there was no easy way to do it without building out the XML. But, this does work.